# pkg_resources.ResolutionError not found

Tags: package, python-3.6

I tried install a package in python3 called Spexxy, using this:

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Using iPython in the shell, I can well import the package with `import spexxy` but when I try to use anything from the package, first I have to use an exclamation point before the command like for example `!spexxytools grid create`, otherwise I have the error:

```
File "<ipython-input-3-b744a07ba8b3>", line 1
    spexxytools grid create --from-filename "lte(?P<Teff>\d{5})-(?P<logg>\d\.\d\d)(?P<FeH>[+-]\d\.\d)(\.Alpha=(?P<Alpha>[+-]\d\.\d\d))?\.PHOENIX"
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But even when using the exclamation point, I now have the error:

```
  File "/home/geoffrey/.local/bin/spexxy", line 4, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').run_script('spexxy==2.3', 'spexxy')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 658, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1429, in run_script
    .format(**locals()),
pkg_resources.ResolutionError: Script 'scripts/spexxy' not found in metadata at '/home/geoffrey/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spexxy-2.3.dist-info'
```

Can you help me find what's wrong ?

Comment: I don't know if this is the solution but, I had the same problem and I just uninstall and reinstall the package again. And fix it

Comment: In the latest version of spexxy I changed the setup.py to use entry_points instead of scripts, so hopefully the problem is gone now. You can also install it via pip: "pip install spexxy".

Answer (score 1):

[setuptools.find_packages()](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#using-find-packages)

> Packages are only recognized if they include an **init**.py file.

So if you put

```py
...
packages = setuptools.find_packages(),
...
scripts=['scripts/spexxy'],
```

you will get this error.

To fix it either write spexxy as a module in your source or declare `packages =` manually instead of using `find_packages()`.

### Edit

[spexxy setup.py](https://github.com/thusser/spexxy/blob/master/setup.py) is using

```py
    packages=find_packages(include=['spexxy', 'spexxy.*']),
    scripts=['bin/spexxy', 'bin/spexxytools'],
```

But the bin directory is missing, so it should be:

```py
    packages=find_packages(include=['spexxy', 'spexxy.*', 'bin/*']),
    scripts=['bin/spexxy', 'bin/spexxytools'],
```